# Как определить куки на странице?

Tags: php, javascript

Вот для мозилы есть web developer и там можно посмотреть инфо по cookie в странице. Но как можно написать токое на php или javascript? Спасибо.

Comment: Больше конкретики

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Куки можно записать / считать с помощью и того, и другого, но на PHP считывать их куда более удобно. Поэтому на PHP, к примеру, это делается так:

**Запись кук:**

```
Setcookie('Name_of_cookie','value',UNIX TIMESTAMP + N)

где N - текущая метка времени + произвольное значение !=0. Это время жизни куки (или 0, чтобы удалить)
```

**Считывание кук:**

```
Для этого в PHP есть суперглобальный массив, содержащий все имена кук и их значения.
$_COOKIE['Name_of_cookie']; // 'value'
```

Comment: а если не знаю имя кука??как можно вывести все что есть??

Comment: Используйте цикл "foreach()":

     Foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $val)
     echo '(Key= '.$key.' Value= '.$val.')';